# cannot connect to oracle server from another oracle client only computer

Tags: oracle, ora-12170

I have one machine as webserver and another as oracle server,
webserver:
- centOS x64
- oracle client installed from http://dony-ramansyah.blogspot.com/2012/02/install-oracle-client-dan-oci8-di.html

oracle server
- XP home x32

I cannot connect to oracle server,

Any suggestion?

on my oracle server (centOS)

```
lsnrctl.exe status :
Security ON: Local OS Authentication
Version: TNSLNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0-Praction
```

on my oracle client (XP)

```
#sqlplus64 system/passwd@192.168.137.3/1521:XE :
ERROR: ORA-12170 TNS:Connect timeout occured
```

I think my oracle server block connection from outer ..

Comment: Have you opened TCP port 1521 in the firewall on your server?

Comment: Your [easy connect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306) string is wrong; it should be `@192.168.137.3:1521/XE`. That isn't the immediate problem as it defaults to port 1521 anyway, but once you can get to the listener it won't recognise the service name, which it will interpret as `1521:XE` in your version, rather than just `XE`.

Comment: ya .. now it's work .. just typo as Alex Poole said

Answer (score 1):

From comments: Your [easy connect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306) string is wrong; it should be `@192.168.137.3:1521/XE`. Your version is connecting to the default port, `1521`, on the server at `192.168.137.3`; but will then look for service name `1521:XE` instead of just `XE`.

But since you're still connecting to the same port this shouldn't get an `ORA-12170`, as the network part is effectively the same. It would expect it to get an `ORA-12514: TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`. Perhaps the Windows version of SQL*Plus behaves slightly differently, though that seems unlikely; the trailing extra space and `:` in the question causes SQL*Plus to show usage information in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

May be your firewall block your port. you can enable this by changing firewall setting.
This is windows 7 configuration to access port
Control panel->system and security->windows firewall->advanced setting->In bound rules-> new Rule(On right hand side)-> select port option with value as  "1521" -> next next....